# save multiple images in custom album in ios5 but not in camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

save multiple images in custom album in ios5 but not in camera roll?

i am using **ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum** example, but it can save only once in custom album and duplicate in camera roll.

i want to save only in custom album through my app.

Can any one help to solve it......

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Albums are strictly "smart albums", meaning that they can only have pictures in them that are somewhere else in the library. You see the same behavior in the Photos app: if you add a picture from the camera roll to an album, you can't delete the picture from the camera roll without deleting it from that album as well.